# a linear system is a bilinear transformation of anyone its circuit elements

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, control-theory

I am reading about dissection theorem and the part below is a bit confusing.

Could anyone one explain it?

> Any transfer function of a linear system is a bilinear transformation of anyone its circuit elements.

[image]

Comment: To what reference does the `[2]` refer? Probably useful to read that or at least post the ref.

Comment: [2] H.W. Bode, 'Network Analysis and Feedback Design', Van Nostrand Company, 1945

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? The reference is a book and I couldn't find that book at library.